# React Calculator: multiple dot issue and equation issue

Tags: reactjs, calculator

I have created working calculator in React, but have two things I need to figure out:

- I want to make sure user can't input a second dot if they already clicked it once
- I want the equation to use the last operator (ex. 5 * - + 5 should produce an output of 10)

I am still a beginner so I need a simple code to make those work and I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks a lot! Here is my full code so far and Codepen link: https://codepen.io/JuliaAyres/pen/dyXGvbO

```
class App extends React.Component {

   constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      display:'0'
    }
    this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this);
    this.equalEval = this.equalEval.bind(this);
  }

  changeValue(event){
    if(event.target.value==='CE'){
      this.setState({display: '0'});
    }else{
      this.setState({
        display: (this.state.display==="0" ? event.target.value : this.state.display + event.target.value)
      });
    }
  }

  equalEval(){
    this.setState({
        display: eval(this.state.display)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <div className="calculator">
            <div id="display">{this.state.display}</div>
          
            <div className="buttongrid">

            <button value="CE" id="clear"  className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>CE</button>
            <button value=" / " id="divide"  className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>/</button>
            <button value=" * " id="multiply"  className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>x</button>
            
            <button value="7" id="seven" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>7</button>
            <button value="8" id="eight" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>8</button>
            <button value="9" id="nine" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>9</button>
            <button value=" - " id="subtract" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>-</button>
            
            <button value="4" id="four" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>4</button>
            <button value="5" id="five" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>5</button>
            <button value="6" id="six" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>6</button>
            <button value=" + " id="add" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>+</button>

            <button value="1" id="one" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>1</button>
            <button value="2" id="two" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>2</button>
            <button value="3" id="three" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>3</button>
            

            <button value="." id="decimal" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>.</button>
            <button value="0" id="zero" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue}>0</button>
            <button value=" = " id="equals" className="button" onClick={this.equalEval}>=</button>
            

            </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the decimal case, I recommend adding a boolean state (let's call it `allowDecimal`) to enable or disable the decimal button, initially set to `true`.

Then inside `render()`, set the disabled attribute of the decimal button to the opposite of `allowDecimal`. The reason is you want to disable the button when `allowDecimal` is false:

```
<button value="." id="decimal" className="button" onClick={this.changeValue} disabled={!this.state.allowDecimal}>.</button>
```

Then inside `changeValue()`, add another if statement to check if the `event.target.value === '.'`. If it is, set the `allowDecimal` state to `false`, which will disable the button. You can set `allowDecimal` back to `true` again when the user presses equals or CE. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: omg it worked !!! thank you so much. one small thing...I realized that I can type in 2.2.2 (instead of it being 2.22)  which makes equation not work. Any ideas on how do I restrict decimals in one number?

Comment: @Julia Your current logic has the `allowDecimal` state being reset back to true each time another button is pressed (if it’s already false). Instead, you’d want to check if the display number contains a decimal or not before updating the decimal button disabled state. There are several ways to check if a string contains a character, such as a `Regex` or using `.indexOf()` to name a few.

Comment: @JuliaAyres Where in the changeValue function are you putting the value check for decimal?

Comment: @MForMarlon I have finally figured it out...I added couple of if statements in the code and all questions seem to pass now, thank you!

Comment: @MForMarlon I have finally figured it out...I added couple of if statements in the code and all questions seem to pass now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This was kind of fun to work out, but there are a few catches (unfortunately, not very beginner friendly):

The code below utilizes the following Javascript methods/expressions:

- [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat)
- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

1.) It's recommended to avoid using `eval` because it can be [unsafe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) and brittle. You can use a library like [math-expression-evaluator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/math-expression-evaluator) to handle stringed math expressions. However, even then, the library doesn't seem to handle invalid expressions (like `1 + 1 +`), so you'll have to `try` and `catch` any errors.

```js
let result;
try {
  result = mexp.eval(this.state.display);
} catch (error) {
  alert(error.message);
  result = "NaN";
}
```

2.) When it comes to the decimal, you'll want to divide your string in an array of strings: `"1.1 + 1.2" => ["1.1", " + ", "1.2"]`. **Why**? Because you want to determine whether or not the last value in the array already contains a decimal and whether or not to update the `display` state if the decimal button was pressed again.

How you currently have it is that you would have to manually check each button value that was pressed and determine whether or not to toggle this `allowDecimal` state if a  `+ , - , * , /` valued button was clicked AND you'll have to determine whether or not to update this `display` state if there's already a decimal (which requires traversing the entire `display` string and locating the last  `+ , - , * , /` instance and then determining if this last value already has a decimal -- as you can imagine, this is very inefficient).

Instead, you can determine whether or not to update the `display` value if the last value in the array already contains a decimal and the decimal button was pressed:

```js
 /*
   split string in array of strings by space(" ")
   
   for example: "1.1 + 1.2" becomes ["1.1", " + ", "1.2]
 */
 const arrValue = prevState.display.split(" ");

 /*
  "lastValueHasDecimal" checks that the last value in the array doesn't contain 
   "." and that the current value of the button pressed is a decimal. 

   In short, if the last value already contains a decimal and the decimal button 
   was pressed, return the previous "display" state; otherwise, update the state.
  
   str.indexOf("x") works by finding the index of "x" within a string
   a value greater than -1 means "x" was found at an index within the string
  
   for example: "1.2" has three indexes: [0, 1, 2] -- arrays start at index 0
   and a decimal (".") can be found at index 1:
   [
     0: "1", 
     1: ".", 
     2: "2"
   ]
 */
const lastValueHasDecimal =
  arrValue[arrValue.length - 1].indexOf(".") > -1 && value === ".";
```

3.) Use a `form` instead of `div`s with `button`s. This makes it more developer-friendly. When using forms, buttons must contain the `type` property with `button` or `submit`!

### Demo

[image: Edit Simple React Calculator]

### Code

**App.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import mexp from "math-expression-evaluator";
import calculatorFields from "./fields";
import "./styles.css";

const initialState = {
  display: "",
  result: ""
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = initialState;
    this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this);
    this.resetDisplay = this.resetDisplay.bind(this);
    this.equalEval = this.equalEval.bind(this);
  }

  changeValue({ target: { value } }) {
    /* 
      setState accepts a function that accepts the current state as an argument
      and expects a state object to be returned:
      (prevState) => { return { ... } };
 
      since you're checking whether or not the last value within "display" 
      has a decimal before updating the state, you'll want to conditionally update
      the state with `value` based upon the "lastValueHasDecimal" expression.

      if(lastValueHasDecimal) is true return prevState.display
      else if false return prevState.display.concat(value)

      prevState.display.concat(value)
      is the same as:
      prevState.display + value
    */
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const arrValue = prevState.display.split(" ");
      const lastValueHasDecimal =
        arrValue[arrValue.length - 1].indexOf(".") > -1 && value === ".";

      return {
        display: lastValueHasDecimal
          ? prevState.display
          : prevState.display.concat(value),
        result: ""
      };
    });
  }

  // if "CE" is pressed, return to "initialState" defined above
  resetDisplay() {
    this.setState(initialState);
  }

  // when the form is submitted...
  equalEval(e) {
    // prevent the page from refreshing, the "default" action of submitting a form
    e.preventDefault();

    // evaluate the "display" expression
    let result;
    try {
      result = mexp.eval(this.state.display);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
      result = "NaN";
    }

    // update "result" with the result of evaluation
    this.setState({ result });
  }

  render() {
    const { display, result } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="app">
        <form onSubmit={this.equalEval} className="calculator">
          <div id="display">
            <input
              className="result"
              disabled
              type="text"
              value={!result ? display : result}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="buttongrid">
            <button
              type="button"
              id="clear"
              className="button"
              onClick={this.resetDisplay}
            >
              CE
            </button>
            {calculatorFields.map(({ id, value }) => (
              <button
                key={id}
                type="button"
                value={value}
                id={id}
                className="button"
                onClick={this.changeValue}
              >
                {value}
              </button>
            ))}
            <button
              type="submit"
              id="equals"
              className="button"
              disabled={!display}
            >
              =
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**fields.js**

```js
const calculatorFields = [
  {
    id: "divide",
    value: " / "
  },
  {
    id: "multiply",
    value: " * "
  },
  {
    id: "seven",
    value: "7"
  },
  {
    id: "eight",
    value: "8"
  },
  {
    id: "nine",
    value: "9"
  },
  {
    id: "substract",
    value: " - "
  },
  {
    id: "four",
    value: "4"
  },
  {
    id: "five",
    value: "5"
  },
  {
    id: "six",
    value: "6"
  },
  {
    id: "plus",
    value: " + "
  },
  {
    id: "one",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    id: "two",
    value: "2"
  },
  {
    id: "three",
    value: "3"
  },
  {
    id: "decimal",
    value: "."
  },
  {
    id: "zero",
    value: "0"
  }
];

export default calculatorFields;
```

If anything doesn't make sense, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: wow thank you for this ! everything really makes sense apart from the eval part...also math expression doesn't seem to work although I added <script src="math-expression-evaluator.js"></script> to html part. just currently trying to figure this out and add to my code instead of eval that I have. for the rest, I have figured all problems out by adding some if statements to my main function